# Has the MLB Division Series Ever had all 4 Series go 5 games prior to 2012?

Tags: baseball, mlb, history, trivia

This year all 4 Division Series Games have gone the distance has that ever happened before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  2012 is the [first time](http://blogs.wsj.com/dailyfix/2012/10/12/2012-mlb-playoffs-game-5-nlds-alds/) since this format was introduced in 1995 that all series have gone the distance.

Comment: Saw on TBS that there is a less then 2% chance that all 4 series could go the distance